# Why is my pidgin microblog plugin no more working?

Tags: pidgin, twitter

Since the begin of this month (march 2013 - for future reference) my [pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) [microblog-purple](https://code.google.com/p/microblog-purple/) plugin is no more able to get my timeline from Twitter. I haven't changed any configuration element. So, is there something changed ? And if so, how can I use it again ?

Comment: Its very likely this has to do with changes to the Twitter API.  If that is the case you would have to wait until the author updates the plugin, it might not even possible, Twitter was very agressive with some of their poicy changes with regards to their API.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin project hasn't released any updates in 3 years and Twitter depreciated the API they plugin was using to access the service.

Plenty of bugs have been opened about this issue however it requires a developer to make the improvements:

https://code.google.com/p/microblog-purple/issues/detail?id=265